# Distance between vertices in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

We know that an unweighted undirected graph $G = (V(G), E(G))$ with the geodesic distance $d_{G}$ is a metric space (if we allow $d_{G}$ to attain $\infty$ or if $G$ is connected)(we'd better say an extended metric space) and if $G$ is a weighted undirected graph then it will be a pseudometric space with $d_{G}$. Now, if the graph is directed is $d_{G}$ still some special function? I mean something similar to a metric, pseudometric, etc. Of course, then $d_{G}$ will be a function from $|V(G)|$, not $|V(G)| \times |V(G)|$. Can we modify $d_{G}$ to get us a good distance function from $|V(G)| \times |V(G)|$ to $\mathbb{R^{+}}$?

Comment: You can still define the distance measure $d_G : V(G) \times V(G) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$, $d_G(v_1,v_2)$ as the shortest (directed) path from $v_1$ to $v_2$. However, this will not be a metric anymore due to, possibly, $d_G(v_1,v_2)\neq d_G(v_2,v_1)$. However, it will probably still be a Quasi-metric, as the triangle inequality should be fulfilled by the definition of the shortest path. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Quasimetrics .

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. I checked: If $G$ is an unweighted directed graph then it is an extended quasimetric space with the function you defined (of course we should define the infinity case as well in your function) and if it is a weighted directed graph then it is an extended pseudoquasimetric space with the same function.